# How to update my function that searches shared words in two lists for search shared words in N lists?

Tags: python, list

I have `N` lists of words, and I want to find the overlapped words between all of them. So far, I came up with the function that can compare 2 lists of words:

```
def sharedWords(l1, l2):
    res = []
    l_s1, l_s2 = set(l1), set(l2)
    for ss1 in l_s1:
        if ss1 in l_s2: res.append(ss1)
    return res

l1 = ["the", "are", "sun", "sky"]
l2 = ["the", "are", "blue", "sky"]
sharedWords(l1, l2)   # output: ["the", "are", "sky"]
```

However, I'm struggling with updating the function `sharedWords` in such way that it can accept any number of lists (but neve more than 10).

For example:

```
l1 = ["the", "are", "sun", "sky"]
l2 = ["the", "are", "blue", "sky"]
l3 = ["is", "are", "sky"]
lists = [l1, l2, l3]
sharedWords(lists)   # expected output: ["are", "sky"]
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the output `["are", "sky"]` in your second example?

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Oh, right. My apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
l1 = ["the", "are", "sun", "sky"]
l2 = ["the", "are", "blue", "sky"]
l3 = ["is", "are", "sky"]


def sharedWords(*lists):
    if len(lists) < 2:
        assert "You should supply at minimum 2 lists"

    return list(set(lists[0]).intersection(*lists[1:]))


print(sharedWords(l1, l2, l3))
```

Prints:

```py
['are', 'sky']
```

Comment: Hmm, `sharedWords([['the', 'ache', 'be', 'lot'], ['the', 'ache', 'get', 'a', 'lot']])` says `"You should supply at minimum 2 lists"`

Comment: @Fluxy: `sharedWords(['the', 'ache', 'be', 'lot'], ['the', 'ache', 'get', 'a', 'lot'])` is how you pass multiple lists to the function.

Comment: @Fluxy Remove the outer `[ ]`: `sharedWords(["the", "ache", "be", "lot"], ["the", "ache", "get", "a", "lot"])`, or use `*`

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ["the", "are", "sun", "sky"]
l2 = ["the", "are", "blue", "sky"]
l3 = ["is", "are", "sky"]

c = Counter(l1 + l2 + l3)
result = [k for k, v in c.items() if v == 3]

print(result)
```

Comment: Probably convert the lists to sets first. If one of the lists contains duplicates it won't work.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: Agree. I assumed that the individual lists won't have duplicates.